# BIGINT and INT comparison failure in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a Hive table with the following definition:

```
create table testforerror (
    my_column MAP<BIGINT, ARRAY<String>>
);
```

The table has the following records

```
hive> select * from testforerror;
OK
{16001:["0034000000a4WDAAA2"]}
{16001:["0034000000orWiFAAU"]}
{16001:["","0034000000VgrHdAAJ"]}
{16001:["0034000000cS4tDAAS"]}
{15001:["0037000001a7ofgAAA"]}
Time taken: 0.067 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

I have a query which filters records with key of the my_column. The query is as follows

```
select * from testforerror where my_column[16001] is not null;
```

This query is executing fine from hive/beeline shell and producting the following records:

```
hive> select * from testforerror where my_column[16001] is not null;
OK
{16001:["0034000000a4WDAAA2"]}
{16001:["0034000000orWiFAAU"]}
{16001:["","0034000000VgrHdAAJ"]}
{16001:["0034000000cS4tDAAS"]}
Time taken: 2.224 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

But however I get an error when trying to execute from spark sqlContext. The following is the error message:

```
scala> val errorquery = "select * from testforerror where my_column[16001] is not null"
errorquery: String = select * from testforerror where my_column[16001] is not null

scala> sqlContext.sql(errorquery).show()
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'my_column[16001]' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires bigint type, however, '16001' is of int type.; line 1 pos 43
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
```

Any pointers are very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DSL and `getItem` method instead of SQL and bracket notation:

```
sqlContext.table("testforerror").where($"mycolumn".getItem(1L).isNotNull)
```

Comment: This would help but I cannot switch to DSL as my query is very complex and I tried to mask the details. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is another option right now. You should open a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK) for that though.